# How to make a horizontal border with circles on the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make a border like this image

[image]

Anyone have an idea to make it? I tried with `:after` and `:before` attributes of `CSS` but with no success.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far so we know what went wrong?

Comment: @Kastriot Beha check my answer below and let me know if any issue

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show your attempt in a functioning snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Check this hope it works.

```css
.circle_outer {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.circle_outer:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px dashed gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_outer">
  <div class="circle">text gies here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi this gives the right visual result but it would be good to have some explanation of how it works including any limitations. For example it relies on the circle having an opaque background.

Comment: The Center point of line depending on the circle, but if you remove-circle it will show on top

Comment: if you want to increase width of line then you need to increase ``max-width: 500px;`` to ``100%`` or something

Comment: Aman, all that information belongs in your answer, not down here.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean the circle border try using this here:

```css
.circle{
  
  width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
  border-color: #DEDCDB;
  border-radius: 50%;
   border-width: 2px;
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: specify it in your question then

Comment: Note the Tidy button in the snippet editor.